# jQuery hiding table category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'd like to ask how can I hide certain categories from a table.

How can I hide the email category with a click of a button?

```
<table>
<tr class='ftable2'>
    <th align="left">name</th>
    <th align="left">email adress</th>
    <th align="right">date</th>
    <th align="right">cat</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left'>email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left'>email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left'>email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left'>email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please format your table correctly. You should be using thead and th's instead of <td><b>title</b></td>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting to hide a specific column?

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2rUk/1/

Use the `nth-child` selector:

```
$('#tableId').find('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Where `n` starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to email cell some class or data-attribute and find it by selector, them hide it.
Like a `<td align="left" class="email-cell">email@email.com</td>`

And

```
$('#your-button).on('click', function() {
    $('.email-cell').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:nth-child()` pseudo selector for selecting second column.For hiding use `hide()` method.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("table tr td:nth-child(2)").hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BXcWA/)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#btn").click(function()
{
$(".email").hide();
});
});
</script> 
</head>
<table>
<tr class='ftable2'>
    <td align="left"><b>name</b>
    </td>
    <td align="left" class="email"><b>email adress</b>
    </td>
    <td align="right"><b>date</b>
    </td>
    <td align="right"><b>cat</b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left' class="email">email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left' class="email">email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left' class="email">email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='left'>name</td>
    <td align='left' class="email">email@email.com</td>
    <td align="right">2013</td>
    <td align="right">msg</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">hide email</button>
```